# Populate Word's field (word template) in Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to populate word templates (word document with fields) with data provided from Windows Phone application and then be able to get preview from Windows Phone app.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's trivial to accomplish.

You could use **DocIo**:

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio

It's not free but it offers you full access to all elements through an object model. And it's written in NET. I don't know about the size of your project but it might be worse the expense.

Another, certainly more "dirty" approach is to use a Javascript library. You could write your app in Javascript and use **DOCX.js**. This is an adventurous trail since there haven't been any updates for two years. But the code is on GitHub and you could extend it to parse your fields.

https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js (http://stuk.github.io/jszip/ is needed as well.)